# Как организовать счётчик в прологе без assert?

Tags: prolog

Вроде же один раз присваиваю переменной Counter значения во время бэктрекинга.

```
readQuests(Counter) :- read(Quest), Quest \= end_of_file, assert(Quest), write(Counter), Counter1 is Counter + 1, readQuests(Counter1), Counter is Counter1; Quest = end_of_file.
```

Comment: файл уже открыт предикатом see, так что проблема в сущности

Comment: Во, решил, добавил вторую переменную.
readQuests(Result) :-  readQuests(0, Result).
readQuests(Counter, Result) :-  read(Quest), Quest \= end_of_file, assert(Quest), Counter1 is Counter + 1, readQuests(Counter1, Result); Result is Counter, Quest = end_of_file.
Это нормальный код? И через assert-ы лучше делать? Точней лучше тянуть переменную через 2 предиката или добавить в базу знаний?

Comment: Для чего именно вам нужен этот счётчик? Что вы собираетесь дальше делать с этими Questами?

Comment: ну дальше я собираюсь  случайно выбирать любой quest

Comment: или добавлять в файлик

Comment: Тогда вам вообще ни счётчик ни assert не нужен. Читаете все элементы в список, определяете длиму списка. По длине `random` выдаст случайное число между 0 и длиной, а затем `nth0` вернёт вам энный элемент списка, считая с нуля.

Answer (score 1):

Введите в базу знаний  фактов предикат с параметром детерминизма - `single`, это стандартное решение для введения счетчика на прологе.